# how to store and fetch encapsulated Arrays data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I would like program a CMS for my WebApplication. For now I use PHP as data source like

```
"bladderTanks" => array(
            "en" => array(
                "0" => "0",
                "1" => "bladder accumulator for up to 1 spare stroke (1x90°)",
                "2" => "bladder accumulator for up to 2 spare stroke (2x90°)",
                "3" => "bladder accumulator for up to 3 spare stroke (3x90°)"
            ),
            "de" => array(
                "0" => "0",
                "1" => "Blasenspeicher mit bis zu 1 Stellfahrt (1x90°)",
                "2" => "Blasenspeicher mit bis zu 2 Stellfahrt (2x90°)",
                "3" => "Blasenspeicher mit bis zu 3 Stellfahrt (3x90°)"
            )
        )

var amountBladder = 1;
var language = "de";

var neededValue = bladderTanks[language][amountBladder]
```

or

```
"signalVoltage" => array(
            "en" => array(
                "12" => "12 VDC potential-free, separate cable, power supplied by customer",
                "24" => "24 VDC potential-free, separate cable, power supplied by customer",
                "56" => "56 VDC potential-free, separate cable, power supplied by customer",
                "110" => "110 VDC potential-free, separate cable, power supplied by customer",
                "115" => "115 VAC potential-free, separate cable, power supplied by customer",
                "230" => "230 VAC potential-free, separate cable, power supplied by customer"
            ),
            "de" => array(
                "12" => "12 VDC potentialfrei, seperates Kabel, Versorgung durch Kunde",
                "24" => "24 VDC potentialfrei, seperates Kabel, Versorgung durch Kunde",
                "56" => "56 VDC potentialfrei, seperates Kabel, Versorgung durch Kunde",
                "110" => "110 VDC potentialfrei, seperates Kabel, Versorgung durch Kunde",
                "115" => "115 VAC potentialfrei, seperates Kabel, Versorgung durch Kunde",
                "230" => "230 VAC potentialfrei, seperates Kabel, Versorgung durch Kunde"
            )
        ),
```

It is annoying to modificate it every time in the Code (PHP-Backend). So I would like to implement an UserInterface for me for both languages, german and english.

I dont know what is the best way to manage those kind of encapsulations in MySQL.

here an hopefully understandable example [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOGaOE)

Comment: It's not clear to me what role SQL would play here. This seems to be about [localization in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608802/php-localization-gettext-or-array).

Comment: I need MySQL to store the data, after I updated an string

Comment: what about phpmyadmin ?

Comment: :) I already use phpmyAdmin, that is not the issue here

Comment: @Schwern I meant MySQL, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First is you're storing formatted strings for each individual variation on the data. Only the data should be stored. Data is flexible and easy to work with, formatted data is not. Formatting should be applied dynamically.

For example, rather than storing `"bladder accumulator for up to 3 spare stroke (3x90°)"` you'd just store `3`. That `3` would be retrieved and then formatted at the last possible moment with something like:

```
$num = 3;
$format = "bladder accumulator for up to %d spare stroke (%dx90°)";
$text = sprintf($format, $num, $num);
```

Then `$text` is displayed to the user. It is *not* stored in the database.

Next we add localization. Basic localization is provided by [`gettext`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). `gettext` works by replacing strings with localized strings from a table of translations you write.

```
$num = 3;
$format = gettext("bladder accumulator for up to %d spare stroke (%dx90°)");
$text = sprintf($format, $num, $num);
```

The `gettext` call would look up the translation for `bladder accumulator for up to %d spare stroke (%dx90°)` in the appropriate language file for your project. For German it would be `locale/de/LC_MESSAGES`. In that file you'd provide the translation with the same formatting options `Blasenspeicher mit bis zu %d Stellfahrt (%dx90°)` and `gettext` would return that.

[Here's a tutorial on using gettext with PHP](https://blog.udemy.com/php-gettext/), setting it all up, and working with the translation files.

`gettext` has its limitations, [you can read all about them](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Locale-Maketext/lib/Locale/Maketext/TPJ13.pod), but it's a good start to localization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MySQL for localization you would need a table called languages for example:

languages table:

```
id (PRIMARY KEY) | language (VARCHAR) |
         1              en
         2              de
```

bladder_tanks table:

```
  id (PRIMARY KEY) | language_id (reference) | amount_bladder (UNSIGNED INT) | text (VARCHAR)         |
         1                  1                       0                              0
         2                  1                       1                         bladder accumulator for up to 1 spare stroke (1x90°)                 
         3                  2                       0                              0
```

And so on, you get the idea.

So now when you need English version you fetch only the records with language_id 1:

```
  SELECT * FROM bladder_tanks WHERE language_id = 1 ORDER BY amount_bladder
```

Same goes for saving or updating:

```
  UPDATE bladder_tanks SET text = "blah blah" WHERE amount_bladder = 1 AND language_id = 1
  INSERT INTO bladder_tanks (language_id, amount_bladder, text) VALUES (1, 1, "blah blah")
```

Your controller actions / functions may looks like this in pseudo:

```
  function display() {
      // SELECT amount_bladder, text FROM bladder_tanks WHERE language_id = 1 ORDER BY amount_bladder;
  }

  function store(array $bladderTanks) {
       foreach ($bladderTanks as $bladderTank) {
           // insert query
       }
  }

  function update(array $bladderTanks) {
       foreach ($bladderTanks as $bladderTank) {
           // update query
       }
  }
```

Hope that gives you a basic idea of how that should work.
I have tried to keep it simple as possible, so I left off the created_at, updated_at extra columns (you should however structure it for your own needs)

Comment: thanks for your help. but your solution is not the best for a lot of data. I dont want to create 1000 tables

Comment: You are welcome, but I still don't see anything wrong with having many tables as long as it helps your application scales.

Comment: You must persist the data because these arrays you have there are loaded into memory and once the script is done executing they are destroyed...another option would be browser cookies, although I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you want the to allow the users to create / read / update / delete (CRUD) bladder tanks ? You want a CMS ? So you must store that data somewhere, because if you keep it in arrays then you would have to modify it every time which is annoying like you wrote

Comment: Exactly, I want to allow the users to read and update those kind of strings in Frontend (CMS). I wanted to save all the data in MySQL all along. But i thought there would be a more 'compact' solution in MySQL then your example. Since I have a lot of Data

Comment: To make it compact the question should be is there similarity between those data sets...if there is you perhaps can build something dynamic, I however can't see similarity between bladderTanks and signalVoltage, other then the fact they are both key value pairs arrays. Not sure there is another way, but its might be because I don't see the entire picture of your idea